# cypher delete node and all the list of related node

Tags: cypher

I'm trying to delete an entire list starting from a given node to the end of the list.

Where is the list of the root,relationship and child nodes. The child nodes can have an undetermined nodes.

```
(r:Root {name:'masterDoc'})<-[p:previous]<-(s1:schema)<-[p1:previous]<-(s2:schema)<-[pn:previous]<-(sn:Schema)
```

When I run the cypher query below I'm getting a Type mismatch: expected Node, Path or Relationship but was Collection

```
MATCH (n:`Root` {name:'masterDoc'})-[r:previous*]-(s) delete s,r,n
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to pull out the longest path of nodes, iterate over the relationships and delete each one and then iterate over the nodes and delete them.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Improvements to Cypher since this answer was posted allow now for nodes to be detached and deleted with a single command.

```
// match the path that you want to delete
MATCH p=(:Root {name: 'masterDoc'} )-[:previous*]->() 
WITH p

// order it in descending order by length
ORDER by length(p) desc

// grab the longest one
LIMIT 1

// delete all of the relationships and their nodes
DETACH DELETE p
```

**OLDER ANSWER**

**NOTE:** This assumes that each node in the path is no longer anchored to anything other than the nodes in the path otherwise they will not be able to be removed.

```
// match the path that you want to delete
match p=(:Root {name: 'masterDoc'} )-[:previous*]->() 
with p
// order it in descending order by length
order by length(p) desc
// grab the longest one
limit 1
// delete all of the relationships
foreach (r in relationships(p) | delete r)
// delete all of the remaining nodes
foreach (n in nodes(p) | delete n)
```

Comment: does not make sense to me, why do a foreach then delete?

Comment: That is just how `FOREACH` is structured. It is really just `FOREACH( loop control structure | mutating operation )`. I updated the answer to reflect some changes in cypher that allow for a new improved approach.

Comment: uh I mean why not delete like this?

`(p:Root {name: 'masterDoc'} )-[:previous*]->()  DETACH DELETE p`

Comment: I like it. I will update the answer. For whatever reason I though DELETE would only operate on a node or a relationship and not a path. I presume you mean the path and not the node p in your query. thanks.